# Disabled buttons look enabled in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, button

Disabled buttons look enabled in Firefox and Chrome. I opened the same page in ie, firefox, chrome and this is the output:

[image]

"DashBoard" and "Calendar" are disabled
"Agent Info" is enabled.

Here I'm using normal asp buttons with css.
What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add css for disabled buttons. Something like

```
input[disabled="disabled"] { /* disabled styles */ }
```

Comment: how can I add this style via C#?

Comment: @Polaris it depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Regardless, I would still use css instead of server side code.

Comment: Your css works if the element has `disabled="disabled"`, but not if the `disabled` attribute is used without a value.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the way they look with CSS:

```
element[disabled]
{
    ...
}
```