# Disabled property does not change the color in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have an html of button with a css class.

```
<button id="btnPrev" onclick="Prev()" type="button" style="WIDTH: 129px" class="buttons" disabled="">Previous</button>
```

in IE it changes the button text color black to gray if i set disabled. but in chrome it works fine but does now change the button text color.

Any help please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194067/disabled-buttons-look-enabled-in-firefox-and-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to style the appearance of a disabled button by doing the following

```
button:disabled {
   /* Your CSS */
}
```

Also rather than do `disabled=""` you need to do `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: Can you provide me the style of IE disabled button text?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS to set the text to gray if that particular button is disabled:

```
#btnPrev:disabled {
    color:gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle : when disabled color change
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8qo5e14/2/)

```
<button id="btnPrev" onclick="Prev()" type="button" style="WIDTH: 129px;" class="buttons" disabled>Previous</button>
```

css:

```
#btnPrev:disabled {
    color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Did you even look at your example?